# How to generate an app token for Agora Chat

Tags: node.js, agora.io

I am trying to integrate messaging/chat in my application, using Agora Chat.

The frontend is made in Angular. The backend is made in NodeJS and I struggle with the NodeJS part.

As I understand it, I must first register my users in Agora Chat and then, they will be able to exchange messages.

There is the [Restful API](https://docs.agora.io/en/agora-chat/restful-api/user-system-registration?platform=web) explaining how to do that. But curiously, Agora does not seem to provide a ready-to-use client for the backend part. At least, not in NodeJS, which I find weird. Did I miss something? I am not the first to have this problem.

1. Am I supposed to make the API calls with Axios/Got etc? Is there really no ready-to-use official NodeJS client ?
2. Most important: I am supposed to use an **app token** in order to call the API. But how am I supposed to get one ? The doc provides an example with a "token server" in Java but I will not put a Java server just in order to generate some tokens for Agora. There has to be an easier solution.

If I call manually the API endpoint from Postman using a temporary token generated from the admin page, it works, so I am quite sure that the API call is fine

I tried to `npm i agora-access-token` but it seems to generate tokens for Agora Signal / AgoraRTC only. Is there an equivalent for the chat product?

Comment: hey man , it would be a lot of help you could help me in setting up agora chat. i am able to generate the token , but on trying to register the user , i am getting failed to fetch.

Comment: there's not much resource for it online,let me know if you can guide me for it

Answer (score 2):

if you want to build chat token, need to use [agora-token](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agora-token) instead. Install with

```
npm i agora-token
```

`ChatTokenBuilder` is included in [agora-token](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agora-token).
Here's a simple code using `ChatTokenBuilder`

```
import agoraToken from 'agora-token'
const { ChatTokenBuilder } = agoraToken

const appToken = 
ChatTokenBuilder.buildAppToken(appId, appCertificate, expirationInSeconds);

const userToken = 
ChatTokenBuilder.buildUserToken(appId, appCertificate, user.userUuid, expirationInSeconds);
```

#### Documentation

- A sample app using node.js & express to run as a webservice [here](https://github.com/CarlsonYuan/agorachat-auth-express)
- Agora Advanced Guide:[Secure authentication with tokens](https://docs.agora.io/en/agora-chat/develop/authentication)
- Authentication workflow refer to this [sequence diagram](https://medium.com/@carlsonyuandev/authentication-server-for-agorachat-sequence-diagrams-da4c2992d2aa)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/chattoken/:channelName/:username', (req, res) => {
  // Extract parameters from URL
  const { channelName, username } = req.params;
  console.log("Chat User name:", username);

  const userToken = ChatTokenBuilder.buildUserToken(APP_ID, APP_CERTIFICATE, username, 3000);
  console.log("Chat User Token:", userToken);
  
  const appToken = ChatTokenBuilder.buildAppToken(APP_ID, APP_CERTIFICATE, 3000);
  // Generate token
  //const token = RtmTokenBuilder.buildToken(APP_ID, APP_CERTIFICATE, channelName, username, Role.PUBLISHER, 6000)
  //const token1 = RtcTokenBuilder.buildTokenWithUid(APP_ID, APP_CERTIFICATE, channelName, username, Role.PUBLISHER, 6000)

  // Send token as response
  res.json({
    rtmToken: appToken,
    rtcToken: userToken
   });
});
```

token will only work if your user is registered in agora user management
you can your agora restful api to create user =>
https://docs.agora.io/en/agora-chat/restful-api/user-system-registration?platform=android

```
const axios = require('axios');

app.get('/registeruser/:nickname/:username/:password', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { nickname, username, password } = req.params;

    const chatRegisterURL = `${chatRestApiDomain}/${chatOrgName}/${chatAppName}/users`;

    const appToken = ChatTokenBuilder.buildAppToken(
      agoraAppId,
      agoraAppCertificate,
      expirationInSeconds
    );

    const userData = {
      username,
      password,
      nickname,
    };

    // Register users with the Agora chat server
    const agoraResponse = await axios.post(chatRegisterURL, userData, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${appToken}`,
      },
    });

    // Assuming you want to send back the response from Agora to the client
    res.json(agoraResponse.data);
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle errors
    console.error('Error registering user:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'An error occurred while registering user' });
  }
});
```