# How do i generate the agora Chat App Temp Token when it expires after 24Hours

Tags: php, node.js, agora.io

The documentation does not mention how to regenerate it. I have tried building a simple token server but the tokens it generates are not working.
Link to token server: https://github.com/AgoraIO/Tools/tree/master/DynamicKey/AgoraDynamicKey/nodejs

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Nodejs Sample Code**

Nodejs sample Code to build appToken and userToken for AgoraChat below

```
const ChatTokenBuilder = require("../src/ChatTokenBuilder").ChatTokenBuilder;
const appId = "970CA35de60c44645bbae8a215061b33";
const appCertificate = "5CFd2fd1755d40ecb72977518be15d3b";
const userUuid = "a7180cb0-1d4a-11ed-9210-89ff47c9da5e";
const expirationInSeconds = 600;

const userToken = ChatTokenBuilder.buildUserToken(appId, appCertificate, userUuid, expirationInSeconds);
console.log("Chat User Token: " + userToken + "\n");

const appToken = ChatTokenBuilder.buildAppToken(appId, appCertificate, expirationInSeconds)
console.log("Chat App Token: " + appToken);
```

Link to sample code https://github.com/AgoraIO/Tools/blob/master/DynamicKey/AgoraDynamicKey/nodejs/sample/ChatTokenBuilderSample.js

Similar post here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75694520/21047572

Hope this helps