How to register a user in agora chat service and generate token with authentication?
please help me for how to register a user for flutter in agora chat
I am trying to integrate messaging/chat in my application, using Agora Chat.
The frontend is made in flutter. The backend is made in NodeJS and I struggle with the NodeJS part.
As I understand it, I must first register my users in Agora Chat and then, they will be able to exchange messages.
There is the Restful API explaining how to do that. But curiously, Agora does not seem to provide a ready-to-use client for the backend part. At least, not in NodeJS, which I find weird. Did I miss something? I am not the first to have this problem.

Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76329434/21047572
