How can I setup user connection using the agora-chat, Is there any api or something for that
chatClient.current.addEventHandler("connection&message", {
  onConnected: () => {
   
    chatClient.open({
      user: userId,
      agoraToken: appToken,
    });
   

    setIsLoggedIn(true);
    console.log(`Connected as ${userId}`);
  },
  onDisconnected: () => {
 
    resetState();
  },
  onTextMessage: (message) => {
   
    setMessages(prev => [...prev, { 
      sender: message.from, 
      text: message.msg, 
      timestamp: new Date() 
    }]);
  },
  onError: (error) => {
    console.error("Chat error:", error);
  },
});

Getting this error when I am using the user token which is made up of (appId, appCertificate, expire). Need an implementation for setting one to one chat in nodejs and react.
For setting up the chat, I am expecting a one to one authentication based chat setup in nodejs and react.

Similar post here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75694520/21047572.
Hope this helps
